# Why does closest select tag return object instead of select

Tags: jquery, closest

Perhaps I have been looking at this too much, but how come the id of the select tag is not alerted...??

here is the code I was playing with:

```
<select id="one">
    <option>an option</option>
    <option>another option</option>
</select>

<button id="btn" >look a button</button>

$("#btn").click(function() {
    var c = $(this).closest(".one").id;
    alert(c);
});
```

that is the hmtl and the javascript...should be an easy one...

Comment: it's an id - just do `$('#one')`

Comment: I am trying too learn other functions...not achieve anything apart from learning other functions, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closest()` used to get the first ancestor element that matches your selector. You need [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) or [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) here:

```
var c = $(this).prev().attr('id');
```

or:

```
var c = $(this).siblings("#one").attr('id');
```

since `select` is the previous element or sibling of your button in this case

Comment: that comment is the best thing I had read all day, thank you! will accept this in two minutes...

Answer (score 3):

[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) returns the closest ancestor element matching the given selector, in your case it is the previous sibling so use [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

But those jQuery traversal method returns a jQuery object which does not have the `id` property so read the id attribute value using [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    var c = $(this).prev("#one").attr('id');//as @Felix pointed out one is the id not a class
    //since you have an id for the select element you can use an id selector
    // like c = $('#one').val();
    alert(c);
});
```

Comment: It should be `#one` not `.one` or just `prev()`

Comment: @Felix missed that in that case why even use the traversal method....just use the id selector and forget it

Answer (score 2):

Because *all* jQuery selectors return jQuery objects, onto which additional jQuery methods can be chained. If you want to access the raw element, you can use `[0]`:

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    var c = $(this).closest(".one")[0].id;
    alert(c);
});
```